# javascript regex to get the content of a string

Tags: javascript, jquery

I have a string

`var str="[a54hy 8:45pm],[f57gh 9:20]"`

i need to get

`[f57gh 9:20pm]`

I don't want to use split since the string length can be anything

Comment: Save the original value before doing your replace.

Comment: is it not possible to cut [f57gh 9:20pm] from the string and add it to a variable

Comment: Not with replace, no, but there are other regular expression tools that you can use.  `String.prototype.match` might do what you need.

Comment: bro...i am not replacing the text..all i need now is how to get that part of the string..

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This worked for me. where id is f57gh

`var re='\\['+id + '([a-z0-9: ]+)\\]';`

`var rematch=RegExp(re,'g');`

`var mydata=str.match(rematch);`

`alert(mydata); //[f57gh 9:11am]`